# What libraries do I need to install if I want to compile Emacs?

Tags: emacs

I am trying to compile `emacs` on Ubuntu 12.04. This is because I want to use Emacs 24.2.

However, I am getting the following error. How can I fix it?

```
checking for long file names... yes
checking for X... no
checking for X... true
configure: error: You seem to be running X, but no X development libraries
were found.  You should install the relevant development files for X
and for the toolkit you want, such as Gtk+, Lesstif or Motif.  Also make
sure you have development files for image handling, i.e.
tiff, gif, jpeg, png and xpm.
If you are sure you want Emacs compiled without X window support, pass
  --without-x
to configure.
```

Answer (score 30):

I used to do it this way:

```sh
sudo apt-get install build-essential texinfo libx11-dev libxpm-dev libjpeg-dev libpng-dev libgif-dev libtiff-dev libgtk-3-dev libncurses-dev libgnutls28-dev
# for gtk2 build replace libgtk-3-dev with libgtk2.0-dev

git clone --depth=1 git://git.savannah.gnu.org/emacs.git
cd emacs
./autogen.sh # not needed when installing from tarball
./configure
make bootstrap
sudo make install
```

To build docs:

```sh
make docs
# or build just the format you want:
make info
make dvi
make html
make pdf
```

But now I just use the package

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:ubuntu-elisp
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install emacs-snapshot
```

Comment: Will it be installing `emacs v28.1`? or whatever the latest one is?

Comment: @alper if you mean via `apt-get`, then yes `emacs-snapshot` means latest "trunk" version. I'm still installing emacs that way, and my current emacs says `GNU Emacs 28.0.50 of 2021-02-12`.

Answer (score 15):

If you run

```
sudo apt-get build-dep emacs23
```

that installs everything that is needed to compile the `emacs23` package. Quite likely that's enough to compile Emacs 24.2, too.

Comment: Or, in Ubuntu 14: `sudo apt-get build-dep emacs24`

Comment: If you are running >=16.04 and get ```E: You must put some 'source' URIs in your sources.list```, see [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/761357/how-to-automatically-update-etc-apt-sources-list-with-source-uris-on-ubuntu-16)

Comment: very helpful, can be adapted for installation of emacs 26.1 on Ubuntu 18.04 or Linux Mint 19 "Tara": `sudo apt-get build-dep emacs25`