# Compile error: checking for libXaw... configure: error: No X toolkit could be found

Tags: compiling, emacs

Can anyone solve this error? After I configure emacs and run make, i get the following:

```
[jroberts@pc emacs-24.3]$ make
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
```

Here is the output when I run `./configure`

```
[jroberts@pc emacs-24.3]$ ./configure
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /usr/bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking whether gcc and cc understand -c and -o together... yes
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep
checking for egrep... /usr/bin/grep -E
checking for Minix Amsterdam compiler... no
checking for ar... ar
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking minix/config.h usability... no
checking minix/config.h presence... no
checking for minix/config.h... no
checking whether it is safe to define __EXTENSIONS__... yes
checking for special C compiler options needed for large files... no
checking for _FILE_OFFSET_BITS value needed for large files... no
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C99... -std=gnu99
checking for gcc -std=gnu99 option to accept ISO Standard C... (cached) -std=gnu99
checking whether gcc -std=gnu99 accepts -g3 -O2... yes
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking for install-info... /usr/sbin/install-info
checking for gzip... /usr/bin/gzip
checking for paxctl... no
checking for makeinfo... no
checking for -znocombreloc... yes
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking machine/soundcard.h usability... no
checking machine/soundcard.h presence... no
checking for machine/soundcard.h... no
checking sys/soundcard.h usability... yes
checking sys/soundcard.h presence... yes
checking for sys/soundcard.h... yes
checking soundcard.h usability... no
checking soundcard.h presence... no
checking for soundcard.h... no
checking for _oss_ioctl in -lossaudio... no
checking for alsa >= 1.0.0... no
checking for linux/version.h... yes
checking for sys/systeminfo.h... no
checking for stdio_ext.h... yes
checking for fcntl.h... yes
checking for coff.h... no
checking for pty.h... yes
checking for sys/vlimit.h... yes
checking for sys/resource.h... yes
checking for sys/utsname.h... yes
checking for pwd.h... yes
checking for utmp.h... yes
checking for dirent.h... yes
checking for util.h... no
checking for sys/socket.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... (cached) yes
checking for unistd.h... (cached) yes
checking for sys/param.h... yes
checking for pthread.h... yes
checking for malloc/malloc.h... no
checking for maillock.h... no
checking for sys/un.h... yes
checking for execinfo.h... yes
checking for getopt.h... yes
checking for sys/time.h... yes
checking for wchar.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... (cached) yes
checking for inttypes.h... (cached) yes
checking for sys/select.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... (cached) yes
checking for utime.h... yes
checking if personality LINUX32 can be set... yes
checking for term.h... no
checking whether time.h and sys/time.h may both be included... yes
checking whether sys_siglist is declared... yes
checking for sys/wait.h that is POSIX.1 compatible... yes
checking for speed_t... yes
checking for net/if.h... yes
checking for ifaddrs.h... yes
checking for net/if_dl.h... no
checking for struct ifreq.ifr_flags... yes
checking for struct ifreq.ifr_hwaddr... yes
checking for struct ifreq.ifr_netmask... yes
checking for struct ifreq.ifr_broadaddr... yes
checking for struct ifreq.ifr_addr... yes
checking for struct ifreq.ifr_addr.sa_len... no
checking whether we are using GNU Make... yes
checking whether gcc understands -MMD -MF... yes
checking for long file names... yes
checking for X... libraries , headers 
checking whether malloc is Doug Lea style... yes
checking for getpagesize... yes
checking for working mmap... yes
checking for dnet_ntoa in -ldnet... no
checking for main in -lXbsd... no
checking for pthread_self in -lpthread... yes
checking for cma_open in -lpthreads... no
checking whether X on GNU/Linux needs -b to link... no
checking for Xkb... yes
checking for XrmSetDatabase... yes
checking for XScreenResourceString... yes
checking for XScreenNumberOfScreen... yes
checking X11 version 6... 6 or newer
checking for librsvg-2.0 >= 2.11.0... no
checking for Wand >= 6.2.8... no
checking for gtk+-3.0 >= 3.0 glib-2.0 >= 2.28... no
checking for gtk+-2.0 >= 2.10 glib-2.0 >= 2.10... no
checking for dbus-1 >= 1.0... no
checking for gio-2.0 >= 2.26... no
checking for gconf-2.0 >= 2.13... no
checking for lgetfilecon in -lselinux... no
checking for gnutls >= 2.6.6... no
checking for gnutls_certificate_set_verify_function... no
checking for xaw3d... no
checking for libXaw... configure: error: No X toolkit could be found.
If you are sure you want Emacs compiled without an X toolkit, pass
  --with-x-toolkit=no
to configure.  Otherwise, install the development libraries for the toolkit
that you want to use (e.g. Gtk+) and re-run configure.
```

This does produce a makefile, but it doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 18):

Take a close look at the output file in your question:

> `[  ...  ]`
> `checking for lgetfilecon in -lselinux... no`
> `checking for gnutls >= 2.6.6... no`
> `checking for gnutls_certificate_set_verify_function... no`
> `checking for xaw3d... no`
> `checking for libXaw...` **`configure: error: No X toolkit could be found`**.
> `If you are` **`sure you want Emacs compiled without an X toolkit, pass --with-x-toolkit=no`**
> `to configure.  Otherwise,` **`install the development libraries`** `for the toolkit`
> `that you want to use (e.g. Gtk+) and` **`re-run configure`**.

So it stopped, and asked you to choose:

- Either you decide to build a text mode only programm. But then, you need to tell configure clearly.
  Run it as:

`./configure --with-x-toolkit=no`

Note, even if you do not want to use GUI functions, it may be good to build with X
support, because the system clipboard it handeled by X, and you may need to access it.

- Or you provide some GUI library, X11 toolkit etc;
  Most probably you need to install some development packages for X
  According to
  [What libraries do I need to install if I want to compile Emacs?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/213873/what-library-i-need-to-install-if-i-want-to-compile-emacs),
  try installing this set of packages - you may already have most of it.

  All in one line:

  `sudo apt-get install build-essential texinfo libx11-dev libxpm-dev libjpeg-dev libpng-dev libgif-dev libtiff-dev libgtk2.0-dev libncurses-dev automake autoconf`

<sub>You want to compile emacs yourself, but if you would only want to install it, Ubuntu has the version 24.3, with and without X: `apt-get install emacs24` or with `emacs24-nox`</sub>

Comment: @Thomas I did not use the code block because I needed to use **bold**, and that does not work in the blocks. Now, there is no bold, but there are the '**' as artifacts - do not belong to the text. I'll revert. I agree that was not easy to see.

Comment: Bold is nice, but it's kinda hard to read, even IF you're trying to make points of it more important.  (This is why I had said read the sections marked with asterisks, in my edit.)

Comment: True, pretty hard to read. My reasoning was that the OP must have seen the text already, but without realizing which part is important. And I had no red. ;)

Comment: I have my own viewpoints and opinions on why they didn't see it, but I'll keep that to myself to stay within the policies here.  Having said this, the bold may be good to make points important, but it isn't pretty NOR easy to read.

Comment: @ThomasW.  Found a hack for a compromise of code block and bold. More readable at least.

Answer (score 4):

You should install the development library of GTK+. It it better to compile Emacs against the GTK+ 3 and not the older version which is GTK+ 2.

```
$ sudo apt-get install libgtk-3-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

During my attempt to install DDD, I encounter an error with the configure command:

`The X toolkit library '-lXt' could not be found.`

After conducting some search, I came across a solution that worked for me:

`yum install openmotif` or `apt-get install libmotif-dev`

Then the error message from the configure command is gone.

While I'm not entirely sure how this solution works, I hope it can assit others experiencing similar issues.