# How to automatically update /etc/apt/sources.list with source URIs on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: apt, 16.04

The following command worked fine on Ubuntu 15.10:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep emacs24
```

However, on Ubuntu 16.04 I get the following error when running it:

```
Reading package lists... Done
E: You must put some 'source' URIs in your sources.list
```

In 15.10 all lines (around 10 in number) with `deb-src` in `/etc/apt/sources.list` where uncommented, whereas in 16.04 the corresponding lines where commented out. For example, here are 4 lines from my current `sources.list`:

```
## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://no.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted
# deb-src http://no.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted
```

What is the reason for this change?

Next, I would like to avoid manually edit `/etc/apt/sources.list` each time I do a reinstallation of Ubuntu. How can this (uncommenting the `deb-src` lines) be done automatically?

Comment: The reason is probably that for most users it's useless time/bandwidth wasting to update the database of available source packages every time.  From the GUI where you configure the used repositories, you can easily disable/enable (comment/uncomment) those lines.  There are also some `sed` scripts around.

Comment: The `python3-software-properties` package might be useful to write a Python script too.

Comment: @JanC Thanks, I wrote my own script. See answer below.

Comment: CLI only version: http://askubuntu.com/questions/496549/error-you-must-put-some-source-uris-in-your-sources-list/857433#857433

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Open *Software & Updates* and enable "Source code".

Comment: Useless if your ubuntu is a server with just shell

Answer (score 15):

I had this same issue on a server install of Ubuntu 16.04, so no GUI. All that I needed was a couple of `sed` commands.

```
sudo sed -i -- 's/#deb-src/deb-src/g' /etc/apt/sources.list && sudo sed -i -- 's/# deb-src/deb-src/g' /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Then `sudo apt-get update` and continue on.

Comment: This worked on 18.04

Answer (score 2):

Here is a (currently untested) Bash script that could be used to uncomment `deb-src` lines in `sources.list` :

```
tempdir=$(mktemp -d)
cd "$tempdir"
source_file=/etc/apt/sources.list
new_file=sources.list.new
perl -pE 's/^#\s+(deb-src)/$1/' "$source_file" > "$new_file"
sudo cp "$new_file" "$source_file"
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: No need for a script. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

simpler solution that does what the others have posted more succinctly:

```
sudo perl -p -i -n -e "s/# *deb-src/deb-src/"  /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Key distinctions:  Perl has the -i inplace option which modifies files in place; I did not add a suffix for backup files because I didn't want the backup files to accidentally be treated as data files.  And " *" deals with optional whitespace.   "perl -p -n -e" is mostly the same as  "sed -e", though watch out for greedy regex matching.

It has the same limitations the others do: it enables sources even if the original wasn't enabled (i.e. partners), and it doesn't work on /etc/apt/sources.list.d.   The following will also process /etc/apt/sources.list.d* but makes a backup first.

```
(cd /etc/apt/; sudo tar cvf sources.list.tar sources.list sources.list.d);  for i in /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*; do sudo perl -p -i -n -e "s/# *deb-src/deb-src/" $i; done
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simplification of @Tobi's result that does it on a single call to sed:

```
sed -i -- 's/#\s\?deb-src/deb-src/g' /etc/apt/sources.list
```

This adds `\s\?` which is an optional white space (note the ? needs to be escaped).